# How do I interpret max drawdown and annualized standard deviation?

Tags: hedge-funds

I'm studying hedge funds and I'm looking at two figures that I'm not sure how to interpret:

The first is Max Drawdown, which I see scaling from 0 to -30ish.

Is Fund A with a MDD of -15 more or less volatile than Fund B with a MDD of -30?

The second is Annualized Standard Deviation, which I see scaling from 0 to 400ish.

Is Fund A with a ASD of 40 more or less volatile than Fund B with a ASD of 350?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum drawdown is the worst top to bottom performance. For example if the fund's value  goes like 100, 105, 92, 94, 90, 100, 110, 103, 112 the max DD is the performance from 105 to 90 which is worst performance an investor could have received due to bad timing.

Annualised standard deviation is another word for volatility.

Comment: Thanks, is MDD a measure of risk then if ASD is a measure of volatility?